# AngularJS: Better way to watch for height change

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm having the old variable height navigation problem: A `position: fixes` navigation on top and a content with `margin-top: $naviHeight` below.
The navigation can change height when data is loaded asynchronously and so the content's margin has to change with it.

I want this to be self contained. So no code where the data is loaded but only in the involved html-elements/directives.

Currently I'm doing it in AngularJS 1.2.0 with a timer like this:

```
/*
* Get notified when height changes and change margin-top
 */
.directive( 'emHeightTarget', function(){
    return {
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ){

            scope.$on( 'heightchange', function( ev, newHeight ){

                elem.attr( 'style', 'margin-top: ' + (58+newHeight) + 'px' );
            } );
        }
    }
})

/*
* Checks this element periodically for height changes
 */
.directive( 'emHeightSource', ['$timeout', function( $timeout ) {

    return {
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ){

            function __check(){

                var h = elem.height();

                if( h != scope.__height ){

                    scope.__height = h;
                    scope.$emit( 'heightchange', h );
                }
                $timeout( __check, 1000 );
            }
            __check();
        }
    }

} ] )
```

This has the obvious **drawback of using the timer** (which i feel kind of ugly) and **a certain delay after the navigation resized** until the content is moved.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This works by registering a watcher in `emHeightSource` which is called every `$digest`. It updates the `__height` property which is in turn watched in `emHeightTarget`:

```
/*
 * Get notified when height changes and change margin-top
 */
.directive( 'emHeightTarget', function() {
    return {
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {

            scope.$watch( '__height', function( newHeight, oldHeight ) {
                elem.attr( 'style', 'margin-top: ' + (58 + newHeight) + 'px' );
            } );
        }
    }
} )

/*
 * Checks every $digest for height changes
 */
.directive( 'emHeightSource', function() {

    return {
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {

            scope.$watch( function() {
                scope.__height = elem.height();
            } );
        }
    }

} )
```

Comment: Do you mean inside `emHeightTarget` instead of using events? this would make the code a little cleaner but wouldn't it break if the two directives are in different/isolated scopes? And my main concern is more about the timer.

Comment: Yep! inside `emHeightTarget`. `$watch` would listen to the height changes. Nothing should break because you are not using an isolated scope for the directives.

Comment: Who changes __height? I don't think this would work, as some code should be updating this variable.

Comment: This would not help you get rid of the timer. But I just want to suggest an alternative to watch for the changes.

Comment: @Scheintod Why dont you check for the height changes only on some events: when the async data has loaded or when user clicks somewhere instead of at fixed intervals?

Comment: @CodeHater: Yes, I appreciate this. (And I must admit that the working of the scopes still bear some riddle for me ...)

Comment: @CodeHater "Why dont you ...": I thought of this. But like I wrote: I want it isolated so that I don't have to care elsewhere. I think putting the two directives in two elements (better would be only one) must be sufficient and this should work without changeing other code (which may not be mine) or creating events whenever something changes somewhere. (There are many places).

Comment: @Scheintod Well in that case I guess you would need a kinda multiple watcher to `watch` for changes on all the models that either update on data load or on user clicks.

Comment: @CodeHater: Perhaps there is some JS/Angular "I'm done and now waiting what happens next" event? Or aren't there any methods of watching the dom or connection element.height to the scope so it could be watched this way?

Comment: @Scheintod AFAIK there isn't any watcher that listens to dom changes. You would need to rely on watching the JS objects for changes.

Comment: Or what about some empty watcher/$digest/timeout magic? Hey, I'm looking for magic here anyways :o)

Comment: @Scheintod I am not totally sure of that :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38172/discussion-between-scheintod-and-codehater)

Comment: I used this solution to determine if a directive is overflowing after it's rendered.  Sounds simple but it's actually a nightmare.  Obviously performing any complex logic in the generic $watch destroyed performance so something to be careful of.  Thanks though!

Comment: is the $timeout dependency injection necessary in emHeightSource? doesn't appear that you are referencing it.

Comment: brilliant, this way it is able to catch even $http related $digest runnings

Comment: calling `height()` will potentially cause a `reflow` which is terrible for performance. `AngularJS` is designed to avoid any `DOM` access during the digest cycle and you are violating this principle. The timer is preferrable.

Comment: How would this directive be used in the HTML. How would one access the value of __height in the controller?

Answer (score 24):

You can monitor height change of your element without using Div, just writing a `$watch` statement:

```
// Observe the element's height.
scope.$watch
    (
        function () {
            return linkElement.height();
        },
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue != oldValue) {
                // Do something ...
                console.log(newValue);
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: calling `height()` will potentially cause a `reflow` which is terrible for performance. `AngularJS` is designed to avoid any `DOM` access during the digest cycle and you are violating this principle. The timer is preferrable.

Comment: This is not propagated from outside. If my element changes height for some reason outside angular, the $watch won't trigger until the next digest loop (for instance when i click on the page)

Answer (score 14):

May be you should watch for `$window`' dimensions changes , something like:

```
.directive( 'emHeightSource', [ '$window', function(  $window ) {

    return {
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ){

           var win = angular.element($window);
           win.bind("resize",function(e){

              console.log(" Window resized! ");
              // Your relevant code here...

           })
        }
    }    
} ] )
```

Comment: Nope. I get `resize` events only if i really resize the browser window. But creative idea nonetheless.

Comment: @Scheintod and what else can change `emHeightSource`'s dimensions?

Comment: Like I wrote: async data loading. (But many other things, too. I have this problem on quiet some places. e.g. clicking on this to put it in that.)

Comment: To make it concrete for this case: this is a breadcrumbs-bar whose path can get so long it line-breaks. the page content and it's path for the breadcrumbs is fetches via json calls.

Comment: @Scheintod i see , so the best solution is what CodeHater suggesting: to check the height after async events and user interactions.. The question is how to do it in directives

Comment: element.height is jQuery method.. not in angular jQlite

Answer (score 6):

I used a combination of $watch and resize event. I found without scope.$apply(); in resize event, the height changes on the element is not always picked up by $watch.

```
   link:function (scope, elem) {
        var win = angular.element($window);
        scope.$watch(function () {
                return elem[0].offsetHeight;
        },
          function (newValue, oldValue) {
              if (newValue !== oldValue)
              {
                  // do some thing
              }
          });

        win.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

This approach avoids (potentially) triggering a `reflow` every digest cycle. It only checks `elem.height()` /after/ the digest cycle is over, and only causes a new digest if the height has changed.

```
var DEBOUNCE_INTERVAL = 50; //play with this to get a balance of performance/responsiveness
var timer
scope.$watch(function() { timer = timer || $timeout(
    function() {
       timer = null;
       var h = elem.height();
       if (scope.height !== h) {
           scope.$apply(function() { scope.height = h })
       }
    },
    DEBOUNCE_INTERVAL,
    false
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote another timer based variant that can be bound to the scope, because, as Jamie Pate correctly stated, direct DOM access inside the digest cycle is not a very good idea.

```
.directive("sizeWatcher", ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            sizeWatcherHeight: '=',
            sizeWatcherWidth: '=',
        },
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ){
            function checkSize(){
                scope.sizeWatcherHeight = elem.prop('offsetHeight');
                scope.sizeWatcherWidth = elem.prop('clientWidth');
                $timeout( checkSize, 1000 );
            }
            checkSize();
        }
    };
}
```

Now you can bind it on any element:

```
<img size-watcher size-watcher-height="myheight">
<div style="height: {{ myheight }}px">
```

So the div always keeps (with a latency of a second) the same height as the image.

Answer (score 0):

This approach watches an elements height and width and assigns it to a variable on the scope provided on your elements attribute

```
 <div el-size="size"></div>


.directive('elSize', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var fn = $parse(attrs.elSize);

    scope.$watch(function() {
      return { width: elem.width(), height: elem.height() };
    }, function(size) {
      fn.assign(scope, size);
    }, true);

  }
}])
```

Comment: calling `height()` will potentially cause a `reflow` which is terrible for performance. `AngularJS` is designed to avoid any `DOM` access during the digest cycle and you are violating this principle. The timer is preferrable.