# How to bind resize using angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I convert this code using AngularJS:

```
$(window).unbind("resize");
$(window).bind("resize", rtResize);
```

I tried to do the following:

```
angular.element($window).unbind("resize");
angular.element($window).bind("resize", rtResize);
```

But I didn't succeed!

Comment: this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change/19049225#19049225 ?

Comment: I wrote above that I tried this!!!

Comment: you mean you want to unbind too?

Comment: yes I want to do both (bind and unbind)

Comment: please show more code, jsfiddle or plunker will help too