# Height of container with ng-repeat directive is zero

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a div with an ng-repeat directive that goes through an array and adds a bunch of divs to my container. When I call `.height()` on the container, which is now filled with divs, it returns 0. It seems to return the height before the ng-repeat directive executes. How can I retrieve the height after all the elements from the ng-repeat directive have been added to the DOM?

I have the following HTML, JS, and CSS code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myController">

        <p>Container height: {{containerHeight}}</p>

        <div id="container">
            <div class="box" ng-repeat="box in boxes">
                Box number: {{box}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.boxes =
        [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

    $scope.containerHeight = $('#container').height();

}]);
```

CSS:

```
.box
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

You can [view a demo of my problem on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A8cdPpjoecaVTkka4IKw?p=preview).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/g4DfdiKX4HO3qW8kVmsF?p=preview

The problem is that the height is being calculated before the DOM is rendered because the DOM rendering is asynchronous. Otherwise, your thread would be blocked while the DOM was rendering and your page would be frozen until the expensive DOM operations are finished. This is the order things are happening...

1. The controller is instantiated and the scope is populated, triggering an angular $digest and therefore the DOM update
2. You calculate the height, which is still zero
3. The digest cycle finishes and the DOM is updated

By doing the calculation inside a $timeout, you can push it to the end of the call stack, after step 3 above and get the correct height

```js
$timeout(function () {
    // calculate height
});
```

Comment: This solution worked the best for me (more simple than a custom directive). Thanks!

Comment: what if I have a `<body>` tag and its background doesn't stretch after `ng-repeat` ? I'm not sure I'll write the `$timeout` in every controller all the time, any suggestion ?

Comment: Check the console and see if the items are being rendered. If so, its just a css issue. You may need a clearfix or to set `body { min-height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 3):

Ok found the problem on plunker.  Replace this

```
$scope.containerHeight = $('#container').height();
```

with this

```
 setTimeout(function(){
  $scope.containerHeight = $('#container').height()
  $scope.$apply();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Or use angular's $timeout service instead of the native setTimeout and you don't have to call $scope.$apply

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that something needs to notify angular synchronization cycle (digest) when the height of your container gets a new value.

there are many approaches, one it is by adding a custom `directive` like below which will get you a reference to the DOM element and you can add a custom `watch` to check the height  and without jquery

**directive**

```
myApp.directive('heightBind', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      heightValue: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        $scope.heightValue = $element.height();
      });
    }
  }
})
```

**usage**

```
< ... height-bind height-value="containerHeight">
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/XQB7MTP9fyXdir2EOopM?p=preview**

- inspiration credit - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19049083/3191896

Answer (score 1):

Div's don't automatically stretch in height to contain their child elements.  You have to do what they call a 'clearfix' hack, set the parent div to "display:inline-block;", or float the parent div.  Just google "clearfix" div and you will find some classes that will fix the div to stretch it's height to contain it's children.  In this case you could do any of these:

```
#container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
 }
```

or

```
#container{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

or

```
#container{
    float:left;
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: This is not the problem. I added your CSS anyway and `$scope.containerHeight` still reports `0` :(
`div`s will stretch in height to contain their child elements. If I float the parent element, then the parent element will not stretch to contain its children. I'm sorry - your answer seems confusing and incorrect. Did you view my Punk or try to get the Punk to work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, at the time your controller is instantiated, the container has no content, therefore, it is zero height.
If you want to get the height, you have to set the scope height, after ng-repeat has executed.  One way to do this is to use timeout.  This isn't a great solution, but does illustrate the issue.  The timeout will execute after the ng-repeat executes.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.boxes =
      [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

  $timeout( function(){
    $scope.containerHeight = $('#container').height();
  },100)

}]);
```