# ng-include height displays as 0 in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-include, ng-switch

### Update:

Using ng-include height is 0. I've provided a totally simplified example below. I need to know how to fix this and make it so the page says Hello.

```html
<ion-view title="Page">
 <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
            <div ng-include="'templates/page30'"></div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Where the templates/page30 file is

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

### Original Post:

I need to figure out how to get my `ng-include` to be shown within an `ng-switch`.  Currently the code does not work.  Two things aren't happening as expected.  The outer button is way small and the ng-included sub-forms are not showing as their height is 0.  Please keep in mind I am using Ionic which means I do not have access to `*.height()`.

NOTE: I'm only showing step 1 of the `ng-switch` otherwise this would be too bulky.

```
<ion-view title="Some Template" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <div ng-controller="someCtrl">
        <ng-switch on="step">
            <div ng-switch-when="1">
                <div height-bind height-value="containerHeight">
                    <ng-include src="'templates/somepage.html'"></ng-include>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-switch>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I have built a directive that looks like the following:

```
llApp.directive('heightBind', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      heightValue: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        $scope.heightValue = $element.prop('offsetHeight');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The template called by `ng-include` is the following:

```
<ion-view title="Services" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>
        <span>Lawncare</span>Services</h1>
    </div>

    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-checkbox">
           Mow Lawn
           <label class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox">
           </label>
        </li>
        <li class="item item-checkbox">
           Trim Plants
           <label class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox">
           </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

One last thing.  The controller `someCtrl` looks like the following: (actual controller reference is missing because I'm currently working within ionic creator)

```
function($scope, $stateParams) {

  // Set the step initially to 1 every time this controllwer is instantiated.  
  // Usually on ng-switch button update the
  // step value via the setStep function provided

  $scope.step = 1;

  $scope.setStep = function(step) {
    $scope.step = step;
  }

  $scope.containerHeight = 0;
}
```

Some of the other things I've looked at to solve this.  I have looked at:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108780/height-of-container-with-ng-repeat-directive-is-zero](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQB7MTP9fyXdir2EOopM?p=preview)

As well as this plunker:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQB7MTP9fyXdir2EOopM?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the height to 0 in the controller:

$scope.containerHeight = 0;

Comment: This Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/XQB7MTP9fyXdir2EOopM?p=preview is what I used as a skeleton. It works for them. Seems you need to init the containerHeight on something.  Incidentally, when I do remove it does not fix the problem.