# AngularJS: Best way to watch dimensions?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

So, I've come up with a few solutions to this and I'm still not quite sure what is best.  First for reference there is one similar question I could find, though it's a bit old.  Here it is for anyone reading this later: [Watching dimension changes in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change)

**The Goal**

I have portions of my app in which responsive height elements are needed.  I want the fastest, most visually appealing way to do this at the UI/directive layer without the need of explicitly broadcasted change events.

**Option One: Directive**

A simple directive can record the dimensions on every digest loop (and resize event)

```
return {
  scope: {
    size: '=ngSize'
  },
  link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

    var windowEl = angular.element($window),
        handler  = function() {
          if ($scope.size &&
              element.outerWidth() === $scope.size.width &&
              element.outerHeight() === $scope.size.height) return false;
          $scope.size = {
            width: element.outerWidth(),
            height: element.outerHeight()
          };
        };

    windowEl.on('resize', function() {
      $scope.$apply(handler);
    });

    $root.$watch(function() { return [element.outerWidth(), element.outerHeight()] }, handler, true);

  }
};
```

**Problem:** The change doesn't propagate quickly enough and visual lag is noticeable.

**Solution:** Using an interval call

---

**Option Two: $interval**

I tried the same thing with an $interval call and it worked, but CPU usage was surprisingly high, even after I inverted control and kept track of elements in a simple root collection watched by value (avoiding concurrent timers produced by multiple instances of the directive).

Aside from some GC-related issue in my environment (I don't see anything that suggests this currently), might there be a better approach to creating this kind of fluid layout?

### Proposed Solution/Question

My first thought would be a way to create a concurrent $digest loop of sorts, to efficiently monitor the DOM as a whole for any visual changes.  Is it possible to efficiently iterate through all computed styles, for example, to produce a cheap hash that can be watched by value?  Something that can be triggered relatively inexpensively every time a relevant computed style is added and/or changed?

Before I build and profile it, could someone comment as to whether it's even realistic, or if it simply makes more sense to abstract/refactor the resize triggers in the first place?

Any other ideas on the preferred way to accomplish this in **1.2.9**?

[edit] **An alternate, perhaps simpler question:** is it even possible to provide a realistic refresh rate of 1-200ms via Javascript in a computationally-efficient manner?  If so, would that way be Angular's $interval, or could a 'VanillaJS' implementation be more efficient?

Comment: Having the double listener (`$watch` and `window.onresize`), ain't there any concurrency/looping cycle issue between those two? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately this question didn't get as much attention as I would have liked... And I don't have time to write a detailed explanation with background, profiler screenshots, etc.  But I did find a solution, and I hope this helps someone else dealing with the same issue.

---

### Conclusion

The $digest loop in any realistic medium-large application will not be able to handle a refresh of 100ms.

Given the requirement of `setInterval` I simply bypassed the loop entirely, instead opting to broadcast a state change only when differing dimensions are detected (using the `offsetWidth/Height` native properties).

Running at a 100ms interval with a single `$root` scope manifest is giving the best results of anything I've tested, with ~10.2% active-tab CPU on my 2.4Ghz i7 2013 MBP--acceptable compared to the ~84% with `$interval`.

Any comments and critiques are welcome, otherwise, here is the self-contained directive!  Obviously you can get creative with the scope and/or attributes to customize the watchers, but in the interest of staying on topic I've tried to omit any superfluous code.

It will monitor & bind size changes on an element to a scope property of your choosing, for N elements with a linear complexity.  I can't guarantee it's the fastest/best way to do this, but it's the fastest implementation I could develop quickly that tracks state-agnostic DOM-level dimension changes:

```
app.directive('ngSize', ['$rootScope', function($root) {
  return {
    scope: {
        size: '=ngSize'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

        $root.ngSizeDimensions  = (angular.isArray($root.ngSizeDimensions)) ? $root.ngSizeDimensions : [];
        $root.ngSizeWatch       = (angular.isArray($root.ngSizeWatch)) ? $root.ngSizeWatch : [];

        var handler = function() {
            angular.forEach($root.ngSizeWatch, function(el, i) {
                // Dimensions Not Equal?
                if ($root.ngSizeDimensions[i][0] != el.offsetWidth || $root.ngSizeDimensions[i][1] != el.offsetHeight) {
                    // Update Them
                    $root.ngSizeDimensions[i] = [el.offsetWidth, el.offsetHeight];
                    // Update Scope?
                    $root.$broadcast('size::changed', i);
                }
            });
        };

        // Add Element to Chain?
        var exists = false;
        angular.forEach($root.ngSizeWatch, function(el, i) { if (el === element[0]) exists = i });

        // Ok.
        if (exists === false) {
            $root.ngSizeWatch.push(element[0]);
            $root.ngSizeDimensions.push([element[0].offsetWidth, element[0].offsetHeight]);
            exists = $root.ngSizeWatch.length-1;
        }

        // Update Scope?
        $scope.$on('size::changed', function(event, i) {
            // Relevant to the element attached to *this* directive
            if (i === exists) {
                $scope.size = {
                    width: $root.ngSizeDimensions[i][0],
                    height: $root.ngSizeDimensions[i][1]
                };
            }
        });

        // Refresh: 100ms
        if (!window.ngSizeHandler) window.ngSizeHandler = setInterval(handler, 100);

        // Window Resize?
        // angular.element(window).on('resize', handler);

    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Hey, just quickly how is this used in HTML <div ng-size="??"></div> not to sure what to put in the quotations

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://snapjay.github.io/angularjs-breakpoint/

which does a lot of what you need, I think. You can watch window width and so on. I'm not sure if it works on height as well, but you could extend it.

Comment: But this doesn't do anything beyond basic responsiveness (horizontal/window size) which is, frankly, easier to implement with Bootstrap & CSS media queries alone...  The goal is to track dimensions of dynamically positioned elements in real-time with the greatest computational efficiency (let's say a rendered group of ~10 - 200 nodes)