# Angular directive - auto stretch to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, typescript

I've got the following layout:

[image: layout]

#### HTML

```
<section>
    <div ui-view="table"></div> // contains the table, height max 20 items

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" ui-view="row1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" ui-view="row1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" ui-view="row1"></div>
    </div>

</section>
```

#### Goal

The idea is to make an angular directive that stretches the annotated container to the maximum height of the parent container minus all siblings.

#### Directive (what I have yet)

```
module App.Directive {

    export class AutoStretchDirective {

        private window: ng.IWindowService;

        restrict: string = "A";

        constructor($window: ng.IWindowService) {
            this.window = $window;
            this.link = this.link.bind(this);
        }

        link = (scope, element, attrs) => {
            var combined = collection => {
                var heights, node, i, len;
                heights = 0;
                for (i = 0, len = collection.length; i < len; i ++) {
                    node = collection[i];
                    heights += node.offsetHeight;
                }
                return heights;
            };

            var siblings = $elm => {
                var elm, i, len, ref, results;
                ref = $elm.parent().children();
                results = [];
                for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
                    elm = ref[i];
                    if (elm !== $elm[0]) {
                        results.push(elm);
                    }
                }
                return results;
            };

            angular.element(this.window).bind("resize", () => {
                var additionalHeight, parentHeight;
                additionalHeight = attrs.additionalHeight || 0;
                parentHeight = window.innerHeight - element.parent()[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
                return element.css("height", parentHeight - combineHeights(siblings(element)) - additionalHeight);
            });

          };
     };
}
```

The directive loads fine, however it's not working correclty. As soon as ng-repeat populates, the container is pushed down to the height required for all items. I've tried decorating the columns with `height: 100%` and `overflow` (css), but it seems to be ignored. Am I missing something? Is there a way to debug the transitions a directive is applying to the elements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Best way to watch dimensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437321/angularjs-best-way-to-watch-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

I've just released a bower component [angular-stretch](https://github.com/TechNaturally/angular-stretch) that does this