# Why using $watch on a directive attribute is not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have directive that use another directive that is setting his property 'gridWidth', but I'm trying to watch that property changes and its not working at all. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
angular.module('myApp')
        .directive('myGrid', function () {
            'use strict';
            return {
               restrict: 'E',
               replace: true,
               scope: {
                   gridWidth: '='
               },
               controller: ['$scope', function(scope) {

                    scope.$watch('gridWidth', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                       console.log("width is changed");
                   }, true);

                }],
                template: '<div element-resize gridWidth="{{windowWidth}}"></div>'

            };
        });
```

The *'windowWidth'* is changes fine and I can see it in HTML dom changes, but the $watch not working for some reason so I can't do anything when it is being updated. Here is the another directive updating the first one with width:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('elementResize', function () {
    'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {

            $scope.getElementDimensions = function () {
               return { 'h': $element.height(), 'w': $element.width() };
            };

            $scope.$watch($scope.getElementDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                $scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
            }, true);
        }]
        };
    });
```

Comment: Try to use it without curlies here: `gridWidth="{{windowWidth}}"` like `gridWidth="windowWidth"`

Comment: And please create some plunk

Comment: its the same. $watch not working

Comment: See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PLwyAXZBztyi5gkuceMv

Comment: is this ok: http://plnkr.co/edit/tJrxmo?p=preview ?

Comment: The width should update on each resize of the screen. don't know why it is now being update...

Comment: it is not that trivial , take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change

Comment: There is a misconception here. Watches aren't being executed continuously, so `$scope.getElementDimensions` isn't being re-evaluated as you seem to expect.

Maybe you can do things related to window size via CSS instead. If so, it will be faster, simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: Wait a minute. Why are you using a two way binding '=' and but then printing the value using `{{ }}`?

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `true` with the `$watch` here.