# Angular directive run if scope values update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a directive that sets the child elements of parent element equal to the height of the tallest child element.  Here's the directive code:

```
    app.directive('equalHeightChildren', function(){
        return function(scope, element, attrs){

            var $tallest = element;

            $.each(element.children(), function(index, child){

                if($(child).outerHeight() > $tallest.outerHeight()){
                        $tallest = $(child);
                }

            });

            element.children().outerHeight($tallest.outerHeight() + 'px');
        }
    });
```

This code runs as the page loads and correctly adjust the heights.  However, I have certain scope variables in my app that can change the height of these child elements (for example checking a checkbox displays a new form in one of the child elements, increasing its height).  I was hoping that the directive would rerun itself when one of these variables changes, thereby re-adjusting the heights of the child elements.  However, this doesn't seem to be happening.

Is there a way to have the directive run when the scope variables change? Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change . I think you'll need some kind of a `scope.$watch` there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to re-run the each you might need a watcher on the element thats changing.
Another option is to a fire an event and have this directive handle it.

```
app.directive('equalHeightChildren', function(){
        return function(scope, element, attrs){

         var setTallest = function(){
            var $tallest = element;

            $.each(element.children(), function(index, child){

                if($(child).outerHeight() > $tallest.outerHeight()){
                        $tallest = $(child);
                }

            });

            element.children().outerHeight($tallest.outerHeight() + 'px');
        }

         setTallest();

       //Use one of these to cause the height to be reset
       //$scope.$watch('myVar', function() {setTallest(); });
      // $rootScope.on('eventTrigger', setTallest);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried this and for some reason still do not see the listener function firing  when I check the box. The box is bound to a value called "order.shippingAsBilling". So my watch function is: `scope.$watch(scope.order.shippingAsBilling, function(value){setTallest();});` It works on initial page load, but when I check the box to change the value of order.shippingAsBilling, the function is not being called again.

Comment: The watch expression needs to be a string.  This seems to have fixed it: `scope.$watch('order.shippingAsBilling', function(value){setTallest();});`