# Watch element's height in angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to `$watch` an element's height in my directive's `link` function.

The height of the element is set such that it's (eventually) equal to the window height. So it should change as the window is resized.

However it isn't updating when you resize the window.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('element', function($interval) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return element.height();
        },
        function(height) {
          console.log('element updated', element.height());
        });
    },
  };
});
```

```css
element {
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
* {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <element>test</element>
</div>
```

I *have* read this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change) but I don't understand why they're using 2 directives or how they're turning out to be helpful. I did try two `$watch`es, similar to what they have done there but it also doesn't help.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('element', function($interval) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('__height',
        function(height) {
          console.log('element updated', element.height());
        });
      scope.$watch(
        function() {
          scope.__height = element.height();
        });
    },
  };
});
```

```css
element {
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
* {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <element>test</element>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `$watch` only gets called once something calls `$apply()` or `$digest()`. Angular won't run watchers for every event as that would make the browser really laggy. Put the `run` section in your main module.

```
angular.module('app', []).directive(...).run(function($rootScope) {
    angular.element(window).on("resize", function() {
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `$watch` here. You can simply add `resize` event handler to `$window` and apply the window height using `window.innerHeight` to the element. Make sure `$window` is injected as dependency.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('element', function($interval, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
          element.css('height', window.innerHeight);
      }, false);
    },
  };
});
```

```css
element {
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
* {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <element>test</element>
</div>
```