# AngularJS: Getting stale results for element dimensions in a directive (1.2 vs 1.3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm fairly new to Angular and am having trouble adding directives to watch the size of elements in response to changes in the page layout.

I'm using a custom directive based on some good examples from a similar question: [AngularJS: Better way to watch for height change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change) , but I've found the watch is seeing the dimensions of the target element before the panel is resized - I assume because the directive runs before the browser renders the changes.

I've put together a JSFiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/aW9dU/139/ . On hitting the 'toggle' button it should update the displayed header dimensions to match the new state of the page. Currently it is showing the previous height of the element. If the $timeout is uncommented then the update loop is triggered.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div id="header" el-size='headerSize'>
        <button id='panelToggle' ng-click="panelToggle = !panelToggle">toggle</button>
        <div id='panel' ng-show='panelToggle'>Panel content. Toggle me!</div>
    </div>
    <div>Header dimensions: {{headerSize}}</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('elSize', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function (newVal, oldVal) {
                //$timeout(function () {
                    console.log(elem[0].offsetWidth, elem[0].offsetHeight);
                    scope[attrs.elSize] = {
                        width: elem[0].offsetWidth,
                        height: elem[0].offsetHeight
                    };
                //});
            });
        }
    }
}])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.panelToggle = true;
});
```

The suggested solution I've found is to use a $timeout to postpone evaluation until after the page has re-rendered but doing this triggers an infinite update loop which can be seen in the console after uncommenting the $timeout line.

What have I missed?

**Update**:

As pointed out below, this works in Angular 1.2.x but breaks in 1.3 (1.3.0, 1.3.5, 1.3.8). The 1.2 to 1.3 migration guide doesn't appear to mention anything that might explain the change.

Comment: You are using very old angular version just upgrade it, It should just work fine without timeout. Check the demo. http://jsfiddle.net/ntqv6c59/. This demo is using 1.2.1 which is still old but much more stable than 1.0.1

Comment: It should be using 1.3.5 in the JSFiddle but you are right it works as expected in 1.2.1. Wasn't expecting it to be a framework thing. Will have a look into the differences between 1.2 and 1.3. Thanks.

Comment: oh yeah you are right. i thought i saw you were using 1.0.1. My bad!!

Comment: I have encountered the same and raised an issue (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12301)