# AngularJS watch element height

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to watch an element height in AngularJS with this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $("#content").outerHeight()}, 
    function(){$("#sidebar").outerHeight($("#content").outerHeight())},
    true);
```

The function does being called and update the `#sidebar` height. However, when `#content` height change, it doesn't update `#sidebar` height. It only change when `$apply()` is triggered.

How can I make `#sidebar` height will be updated as soon as the `#sidebar` height is changing?

Comment: You should never have DOM manipulation code in your controller btw.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz It was never specified that this is in a controller. Scope is available in directives.

Comment: Did you try these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change