# Trying to avoid the use of $watch

Tags: jquery, angularjs

The code snippet below alters a DOM element when the element is smaller than 700px width. 
My question is, how can I do the same thing without using a watcher?

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
                    return $('#calendar').width();
                }, function () {
                    if ($('#calendar').width() < 700) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Have you checked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already using jQuery you might use the [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) method:

```
$("#calendar").resize(function(){
    if ($(this).width() < 700) {
        $(this).fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
    }
});
```

You might additionally need to execute the same code on initial load of your div.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the same effect with `eventListener`.

Something like this:

```
function checkWindowWidth () {
    if ($window.innerWidth < 700)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');    
    $scope.$apply();
};

window.addEventListener('resize', checkWindowWidth);
window.addEventListener('load', checkWindowWidth); // or check on load
```

If you are using underscore, it has a good utility function for `debounce`, and it's recommended to use a debounce function on resize.

```
var checkWindowWidth = _.debounce(function() {
    if ($window.innerWidth < 700)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');    
    $scope.$apply();
}, 10, true);

window.addEventListener('resize', checkWindowWidth);
window.addEventListener('load', checkWindowWidth); // or check on load
```

Comment: `_.debounce` what is `_` here?

Comment: It's underscore's debounce function

Comment: "underscore" there is no tag of it in the question.