# $watch height of element and change on another

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Is there a way to make something like:

I have a `navigation bar` with `class: "navbar-fixed-top"`, and I also add a style `min-height: 50px;`

I have also a `content` below the navigation bar, with class style `padding-top: 70px;`

The problem is - if I resize the window to smaller, and the height of navigation bar will increase the content below the navigation bar is hidden under the navigation bar.

> How to $watch the height of navigation bar to change the style of
>   content class "padding-top" into greater value?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19049083) solution, but I have to watch one element, and if there is a change I have to assign something into another element

**Important: just in Angular, not jQuery**

The picture with some explanation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by using jqLite (built into Angular.js). Sadly there is no way we can catch the window change event with just Angular.js version 1.

I've created a small jsfiddle to show you, how to do this cleanly: https://jsfiddle.net/tmmust0r.

What you must do is `angular.element` the `$window` object to make the jqLite events available and watch the resive event. On this resize event you have to call `$scope.$apply();` so angular knows something has changed.

When returning this in the watch function, this will be triggered, and it will call the watch callback if the value has changed.

By knowing the window width, you can probably also see when the navigation bar breaks or not. If not you could change the window resize event to any other jqLite event and do the same thing.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $window.innerWidth; // Return the window width value
}, function(newValue) {
    $log.info('Width changed!', newValue);
});

angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {
    $scope.$apply(); // Make sure the scope knows something has changed
});
```