# element height watcher is not working properly inside the angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, watch

```
     <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl" style="border:1px solid;height:300px;width:100%">
       <my-movie>
          Movie Title :
       </my-movie>
     </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.movies = ['Ice Age', 'Frozen'];
    });
    app.directive('myMovie', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h1>affaw</h1>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          scope.$watch(function() {   //<--not triggering
            return element[0].parentElement.clientWidth;
          }, function(newValue, oldValue) {

         if(newValue!=oldValue){
            alert("Newvalue - " + newValue + "- Old value - " + oldValue);
          }

          }, true);

        }
      };
    });
      </script>
```

This is working initially only when the page is first loaded after even though width is changing (resize the window to change its width) this not working.so,I thought of watch only got called once.so I have tried `$scope.apply`but an error occured then `rootScope]:inprog Error` I guess the problem is with the scopeCan anyone please say where am i going wrong?

Expected behaviour: whenever width of div changes (resize the window to change its width) it has show the old value and new value in alert.

[Demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/hcysOi470bJKtZxaqIML?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Better way to watch for height change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048985/angularjs-better-way-to-watch-for-height-change)

Comment: can you please explain.?

Comment: What is there to explain? You can take the code from the accepted answer and change "height" to "width" and you're on your way.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan tried..not working.please see the demo

Comment: The demo shows the same code as you already had. You need to [edit] your question to show how you've tried it and what exactly is not happening.

Comment: what i have tried is there in the question and in the demo and what's not happening is when the size of the div is changing the values are not being updated and trigger a alert box

Comment: can you please explain what's going wrong here.I have been trying this but i am not able to know where i am wrong