# How Can I Split this form in two values

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can i end up with two values after submit okay i was wondering how can i have the hidden value and another value containing the div text?? the reason why it because im going to insert both of those values in different variables to insert into a mysql query

html code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return insert_value()">
    <input id="hidden_data" name="data" type="hidden" value="<?php $user_id ?>"/>
        <div id="showing_data" class="commenttext" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitthis" />
</form>
```

Javascript CODE:

```
function insert_value()
{
  var values = [];
    values.push(document.getElementById('hidden_data').value);
    values.push(document.getElementById('showing_data').textContent);
    console.log(values);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a `textarea` instead of `div` with `contenteditable`? If you absolutely want it this way, you could just create another hidden input, no need to place both values in one input.

Comment: i dont use textarea because people can use the bottom right hand corner to drag it down and i dont want that to happen

Comment: @Colandus What if i place the value from field 1 ?? how would i fetch the 2nd value????????????

Comment: Make another hidden input and place the html from the div inside of it in your submit callback. I will update my post with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `div` with `textarea` and to disable resizing use css:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

---

To answer your real question, but slightly modifying it; instead of merging them both in one input create another hidden input.

in HTML add this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data_result" id="data_result" />
```

And your javascript code:

```
function insert_value()
{
    var html = document.getElementById('showing_data').textContent;
    document.getElementById('data_result').value = html;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: but when i type and say i indent i want it to auto height, get taller

Comment: There are several ways to make the `textarea` auto resize, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height

Answer (score 0):

just replace the div with textarea  and add  `style = "resize:none"` to the text area

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return insert_value()">
        <input id="hidden_data" name="data" type="hidden" value="<?php $user_id ?>"/>
            <textarea style = "resize:none" id="showing_data" class="commenttext" contenteditable="true"></textarea >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitthis" />
    </form>
```

and change following line in the javascript

```
document.getElementById('showing_data').value;
```

Comment: Its draggable idont want it to be draggable

Answer (score 0):

you can make it textarea and you can have hidden value of that.

```
    <textarea id="showing_data"  rows="4" cols="50">
```

and if you dont want to be draggable just use this in css

```
 textarea
{
 resize: none;
}
```