# How to break new line if text longer than text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to break new line if text longer than textBox in c#. Because when I try count the character and than break it is not useful. What is my system When I write the text into the `TextBox` if the text longer than `TextBox` I want it to break and Enter new line the result should be under form below

Result should be like this in c#:

```
  ______________________________________
 |                                      |
 |GOOD MORNING EVERY ONE CAN YOU HELP ME|I HAVE A GIB PROBLEM PLEASE TELL ME......
 |______________________________________|


[ button ]
```

The result should be:

```
-  GOOD MORNING EVERY ONE CAN YOU HELP ME
-  I HAVE A GIB PROBLEM PLEASE TELL ME......
```

Comment: This only works for multi line (aka "Text area") text boxes. To make it _look_ like a single line at first sight, use a ["Text area auto height" solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `Wrap` or `WrapText` option. You should set it to `true`. 
**EDIT:** And set the `TextMode` to `TextBoxMode.Multiline`.

Comment: "This property is applicable only when the TextMode property is set to TextBoxMode.MultiLine."

Answer (score 1):

You should set [WrapText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.wrap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Option of TextBox to True.

Also set `TextMode` property to `TextBoxMode.MultiLine`. (Thanks to Uwe Comment on my answer).

Comment: "This property is applicable only when the TextMode property is set to TextBoxMode.MultiLine."

Answer (score 0):

Set WrapText Option of TextBox to True, and set the TextMode to TextBoxMode.Multiline.

Comment: Sorry, I loaded the page and got distracted. When I came back I hit post and then reloaded the page.

Comment: Be quick or be dead ;-)