# javascript, controlling a ball's movement using mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I was following this MDN tutorial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Games/Workflows/Famoso_juego_2D_usando_JavaScript_puro/Mueve_la_bola

And I was wondering how could we control the ball's movement using mouse movement event.

I have seen that mousemove works with textarea and some inputs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove

I thought if we could put a textarea behind the canvas, we could detect the event, get the mouse's position and let the user change the ball's movement with mouse movement.

I have read:

[Dynamically resize textarea width and height to contain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817804/dynamically-resize-textarea-width-and-height-to-contain-text)

So I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Juego</title>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            background: #eee;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="ta" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<script>
    const textarea = document.getElementById('ta');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    textarea.style.height = canvas.height;
    textarea.style.width = canvas.width;

    let x = canvas.width / 2;
    let y = canvas.height - 30;

    const dx = 2;
    const dy = -2;

    let drawBall = function () {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };

    function draw(e) {
        console.log(e);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        drawBall();

        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    setInterval(draw, 10);

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected output would be to have the textarea using canvas' width and height, and being behind it; however it is smaller and put on top left:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the `textarea` to capture the event, and it'll be complicated because the `canvas` will be on top and the `textarea` will never know the mouse is moving on top of it, and to make the ball moving with the mouse, you have to passe the `x` and `y` of the mouse to the `draw();` while it's moving function

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vqdyLx5u/22/

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawBall(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw(x, y) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBall(x, y);
}

draw(canvas.height / 2 , canvas.width / 2); // initial draw

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  draw(e.pageX, e.pageY); // the coordinates of the mouse
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```