# trouble in entering text in dynamically changing textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not so sure of how to ask my question.
Actually i'm having a textarea and a button, if i click the button it will show some text in the textarea and then user need to type some more text to it.
I like to have a dynamic textarea (ie, the height of the textarea will change based on the content entered) so i coded for it.

My code works fine. But while the user entering some text, they can't see the exact line where they are typing.

This problem occurs only when the textarea is near the end of the screen.(Unfortunately i need to have my textarea there. so here i have given some `<br>` tag to move the textarea to the end of the screen)

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sris/24yf5n3x/)

And my code comes here:

```
<script>
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
    o.style.height = "1px";
    o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";
    $("#text").focus();
}
function click1()
{

    document.getElementById('text').value="Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,[5][6] created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky,[7][8] as a more open alternative to earlier Q&A sites such as Experts Exchange. The name for the website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog.[9]";
    textAreaAdjust(document.getElementById('text'));
    $("#text").focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden" id="text"></textarea>
<input type="button" onClick="click1()">
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: You mean text area should be expanded from TOP side ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com yeah exactly...

Comment: @treegarden it works as same. removal of 25 pixels from `o.style.height` doesn't give any difference.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com But how can i make like this?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24yf5n3x/2/)

I added

`$(window).scrollTop($('#text').height() + $('#text').offset().top);`

Basically to scroll to the bottom of your textarea position.

Answer (score 1):

you can put the textarea at the end of the screen using css

```
 textarea { 
    position: absolute,
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
 }
```

I have updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24yf5n3x/3/):