# Trigger directive on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I using elastic directive for resizing textarea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24090733/1657065).
But i using ng-show for textarea, and on click `height` of textarea is `0`.
So i need to use $watch somehow to trigger directive on click, but don't know how.

Html:

```
<textarea ng-show="showOnClick" elastic ng-model="someProperty"></textarea>
<a ng-click="showOnClick = true"> Show text area </a>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('elastic', [
    '$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element) {
                $scope.initialHeight = $scope.initialHeight || element[0].style.height;
                var resize = function() {
                    element[0].style.height = $scope.initialHeight;
                    element[0].style.height = "" + element[0].scrollHeight + "px";
                };
                element.on("input change", resize);
                $timeout(resize, 0);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zjcbomxd/1/)

Comment: not sure I understood what you're trying to accomplish but it seems like you are looking to run resize on either focus keyup or keydown right?

Comment: @Jony-Y This directive resize textarea depends on content. But if textarea s hided on load and then shown on click the height is 0, so it invisible. I try to run `resize` on click.

Comment: this is a textarea, so click would be focus ... or mousedown

Comment: trigger directive on click outside textarea `<a ng-click="showOnClick = true"> Show text area </a>`

Comment: ok I got what you want... just create a quick plunker and Ill help... basically what you want to do is either run an init function on the directive setting a default size... or nicer just add the attr parameter to the directive and observe the ng-show attr and on change run the resize or instead of ngShow just pass the showOnClick to the directive and $watch it and run resize accordingly

Comment: @Jony-Y Thanks here is http://jsfiddle.net/zjcbomxd/1/

Comment: @Jony-Y Here is solution with observe ngShow http://jsfiddle.net/zjcbomxd/2/. You can post as an answer and  i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as requested, the solution is to $watch the ngShow attr and run some sort of init function when the value is true.

[user produced jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjcbomxd/2/)
example code:

```
 .directive('elastic', [
    '$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngShow: "="
            },
            link: function($scope, element, attr) {
                $scope.initialHeight = $scope.initialHeight || element[0].style.height;
                var resize = function() {
                    element[0].style.height = $scope.initialHeight;
                    element[0].style.height = "" + element[0].scrollHeight + "px";
                };
                 if (attr.hasOwnProperty("ngShow")) {
                    function ngShow() {
                        if ($scope.ngShow === true) {
                            $timeout(resize, 0);
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.$watch("ngShow", ngShow);
                    setTimeout(ngShow, 0);
                 }
                element.on("input change", resize);
                $timeout(resize, 0);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```