# How to create a textbox inside gridstack so that it fits the entire grid-item-content?

Tags: javascript, gridstack

I am using the following:

```
https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/
```

For each grid-stack-item, I have a grid-stack-item-content div. Within each, I have 2 divs with class .panel-header that has the title of the box/panel and a textarea under that. The issue is, the textarea is never fitting the whole height of the panel even when I set the height of the textarea to be 100% in both width and height.

Answer (score 0):

textarea doesnt work with regular height style, it has the rows attribute

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

if you increase or decrease the rows it will get bigger or smaller
to do this automatically you need to combine the resize event of gridstack with some solution already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height)