# Resize textarea automatically?

Tags: javascript

I have this part of code :

```
let o = document.getElementById("name");
        let a  = document.getElementById('customerstype');
        let p = document.getElementById("parent");
        let h  = document.getElementById('hierarchy');
        let s  = document.getElementById('status');
        o.style.height = (o.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
        a.style.height = (a.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
        p.style.height = (p.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
        h.style.height = (h.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
        s.style.height = (s.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
```

And for every textarea i have i need to say `document.getElementyById`. Is there any other way to do this and not to have 10lines of code, but to have unique for every textarea.

Comment: Use class instead of id

Comment: if i use class i  cant access o.style.height ?

Comment: does this code run on onChange of the textarea?

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/   < if > `jquery` can be used

Comment: on init in angular

Comment: @None Use class and then a for loop to iterate over all the collection.

Comment: i dont want to use jquery!

Comment: @abhishekkannojia will that add same height on all textareas? Because i want to autoresize textarea depends on content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class and then a for loop to iterate through all the elements:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.txtarea'); // Assuming class txtarea
elements.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.height = (elem.scrollHeight - 10) + 'px';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function check(t){ 
  t.style.height = (t.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
}
```

```css
textarea{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="name" onkeydown="check(this)"></textarea>
<textarea id="customerstype" onkeydown="check(this)"></textarea>
<textarea id="parent" onkeydown="check(this)"></textarea>
<textarea id="hierarchy" onkeydown="check(this)"></textarea>
<textarea id="status" onkeydown="check(this)"></textarea>
```

I don't quite understand you demand, but i hope this can be helpful

Comment: How can i have on init automatically resized textarea? Now is only when i enter

Comment: "automatically resized textarea" means when you type things into textarea , as more things you input as the textarea become higher?

Comment: yes.. but on start i will have some data in textarea so i want to resize textarea depends on that data

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height) this may help you

Comment: this is jquery i dont want to use jquery

Comment: You just need to replace the grammar, it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use class as I mentioned in comments like this --

```
<textarea id="name" class="myTextArea"></textarea>
<textarea id="customerstype" class="myTextArea"></textarea>
<textarea id="parent" class="myTextArea"></textarea>
<textarea id="hierarchy" class="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

Loop through class elements-

```
let o = document.getElementsByClassName("myTextArea");
for(var ele in o){
    o[ele].style.height = (o.scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
}
```

Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/cr5ss9L0/

Comment: it not add height only scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')`(if your textAreas have a common class) or `document.getElementsByTagName('tag_name')`. These function return a `NodeList` object, but you can think of it as an array of DOM elements, on which you can use `style` property. Like others have said, the quickest way to set the style property on all of these elements is using a for loop ( or better a foreach loop).