# Bootstrap input for send message

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want do textarea or input for send message.
I have form, where I have input for message and button send. 
How I can do input autoresize when user write message?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="list-group">

<li class="list-group-item">New Message</li>

</ul>

<form>

<textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

How I can autoresize this textarea when I write message?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height

Comment: Check : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/P351