# Is it possible to make HTML textarea auto-width too? Basically both auto-width and auto-height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

There are plenty of StackOverflow examples of an auto-height Textarea. One example is this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24676492/1634905

```
<textarea oninput="auto_grow(this)"></textarea>

textarea {
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 100px;
}

function auto_grow(element) {
    element.style.height = "auto";
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

Is there a similar solution that contains auto-width too? Basically both auto-width and auto-height?

When I try a similar way to retrieve the `element.scrollWidth`, it continues to give me the original width of the text area.

https://jsfiddle.net/on7zasd3/

---

**EDIT:**

I think I figured it out. (Ps, I am not sure why the code formatting is broken after here on StackOverflow?)

1. I had to specify `cols="1"` on the text area
2. I also had to perform the `element.style.width = "auto";` and set the texture's width to that before performing the height `auto` one.
3. Textarea also requires `white-space: nowrap;` CSS:

   function auto_grow(element) {
   element.style.width = "auto";
   console.log(element.scrollHeight+", "+element.scrollWidth)
   element.style.width = (element.scrollWidth)+"px";

   ```
    element.style.height = "auto";
    console.log(element.scrollHeight+", "+element.scrollWidth)
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
   ```

   }

   textarea {
   resize: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   min-height: 30px;
   min-width: 30px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   }

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

1. I had to specify `cols="1"` on the text area
2. I also had to perform the `element.style.width = "auto";` and set the texture's width to that before performing the height `auto` one.
3. Textarea also requires `white-space: nowrap;` CSS

   function auto_grow(element) {
   element.style.width = "auto";
   console.log(element.scrollHeight+", "+element.scrollWidth)
   element.style.width = (element.scrollWidth)+"px";

   ```
    element.style.height = "auto";
    console.log(element.scrollHeight+", "+element.scrollWidth)
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
   ```

   }

   textarea {
   resize: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   min-height: 30px;
   min-width: 30px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   }

https://jsfiddle.net/on7zasd3/3/